# Valuation rings over a field that is algebraic over a finite subfield, are there any?

Tags: commutative-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field, valuation-theory

I am studying an article by Koji Sekiguchi and am stuck at a corollary that states:

$Zar(K) =\{K\} $ if and only if $K$ is an algebraic extension over a finite field.
Where $Zar(K)$ denotes the set of all valuation rings with quotient field $K$

This result follows a lemma that states:

Let $K$ be a field and $A$ a subring of $K$.
The next three conditions are equivalent:

-$Zar(K\mid A)$={$K$}  $\ \ \ $ (($Zar(K\mid A)$ is simply the set of valuation rings containing the ring $A$))

-$K$ is an integral extension over $A$.

-$A$ is a field and $K$ is an algebraic extension over $A$.

I am still struggling with how is it sufficient for $K$ to be an algebraic extension over just one finite field, in order for it to contain no valuation rings.
Here's a citation for the article:

*Sekiguchi, Koji*, [**Prüfer domain and affine scheme**](http://dx.doi.org/10.3836/tjm/1270132261), Tokyo J. Math. 13, No. 2, 259-275 (1990). [ZBL0726.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0726.14001).

Comment: Just apply the lemma with $A$ equal to the prime field.

Comment: The prime field has no valuation rings. Every element of every algebraic extension of every finite field (some redundancy there) is integral over the prime field.

Comment: Another basic argument is that if a field $A$ is algebraic over a finite field, then each element $a \in A^*$ has finite multiplicative order, so its valuation (written additively) must be $0$, i.e. there are no nonzero elements with non-trivial valuation.